# in VS Code there is an extension "Increment Selection" to increment numbers in the code. Does it exist for Visual Studio Community too?

Tags: visual-studio-code, increment

Sometimes I have code where I have to insert consecutive values. This is a problem with big files.
First I make them all the same, after which I increase the value 1 by 1.. Such as:

```
<div>a1</div>
<div>a1</div>
<div>a1</div>
<div>a1</div>
<div>a1</div>
<div>a1</div>`
```

becomes:

```
<div>a1</div>
<div>a2</div>
<div>a3</div>
<div>a4</div>
<div>a5</div>
<div>a6</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

Found sort of an answer by installing VS-Code; install "Increment Selection" and reload file in VS-Community.

Answer (score 10):

You can try out Emmet abbreviation feature in Visual Studio Code.

According to [Emmet in Visual Studio Code - visualstudio.com](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet), Emmet is a build-in feature in Visual Studio Code. No extension is needed!

> Emmet snippets and expansions is build right into Visual Studio Code.

---

## Example

1. Type following characters on Visual Studio Code in a html file (or any file supported by this feature, [see more](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_how-to-expand-emmet-abbreviations-and-snippets)).

   ```
   div{a$}*6
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It will expand Emmet abbreviations to this:

   ```
   <div>a1</div>
   <div>a2</div>
   <div>a3</div>
   <div>a4</div>
   <div>a5</div>
   <div>a6</div>
   ```

You can find more Emmet syntax on [Emmet Documentation - emmet.io](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/).

Comment: this is the answer.

Comment: @a_a what's going on here?

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [Incrementor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nmsmith89.incrementor) plugin, it works on various cases.

Comment: It is marked "VSCode Extension"... not for VSCommunity

Comment: it kind of does a different thing, it doesn't allow incrementing different lines by different amounts

Answer (score 1):

Another extension that will do the job is [VSCode Progressive Increment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=narsenico.vscode-progressive-increment).
I think is more user friendly than "Increment Selection" (mentioned in an answer by @backnext) since it doesn't require multiple cursors.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Text [Text Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qcz.text-power-tools) which allows you to insert a number sequence with custom starting point and at custom increments. It also allows you to do a bunch of other stuff like make a selection upper or lower case, as well as inserting lorem ipsum paragraphs, encoding, line sorting, etc

Comment: Seems to be nice but again "VSCode Extension"... not for VSCommunity